# Zendesk frontend translation

Tags: inline-translations

Zendesk has a default translation file located at app/locale/lang_code/Zendesk_Zendesk.csv

The translations work perfectly in the admin section but not in the frontend.

In the frontend I'm using the same code as they use in the default adminhtml code
example:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('zendesk')->__('Open Ticket') ?>
```

In the file app/code/community/Zendesk/Zendesk/etc/config.xml

I copied the following code

```
<translate>
        <modules>
            <translations>
                <files>
                    <default>Zendesk_Zendesk.csv</default>
                </files>
            </translations>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

from the adminhtml tag and pasted it inside the frontend tag. But even after reindexing and clearing the cache the translations do not show up. But many online tutorials mention this as being sufficient. What am I doing wrong to translate the zendesk module frontend as well? (Feels like this should be a default feature anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Do you have the correct language in frontend configured?
- Is the file actually loaded?
- Are you in developer mode? Which only shows translation located in the correct module (which should be the case - SHOULD)

Comment: Yes the correct language is configured in the fronted. How do I check if the file is actually being loaded? And no I am no longer in developer mode.

Comment: xdebug and a breakpoint in `\Mage_Core_Model_Translate::_loadModuleTranslation`